# keyboard squishes percentrelativelayout layout

Tags: xamarin.android, android-percentrelativelayout

I have been working on (xamarin.android) project using percentrelativelayout and have come across a problem. When the soft keyboard is displayed it squishes the entire layout. Is, there a way to resolve this? Like how to set the keyboard on top of the layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding a tag in the mainactivity.cs file "WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustPan".